# Extensão .Class no arquivos de PHP

Tags: php

Estudando alguns códigos na web encontrei alguns arquivos que usam `.class.php`. Qual a diferença desse tipo para os `.php`.

Comment: Continua sendo arquivo texto, o nome vai ser arquivo.class com extensão php

Comment: mas qual a diferença?

Comment: só o no nome, você pode utilizar para dizer que o arquivo php possui uma classe, só para deixar organizado, mas não altera em nada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esses arquivos tem um `.class` antes.

De verdade, é só isso que tem diferente, porque você pode usar o nome que quiser. Não tem nada que exija isto. É uma convenção que algumas pessoas adotaram. O que vai dentro pode ser qualquer coisa, embora algumas pessoas costumem colocar uma classe dentro deste arquivo. Nada impede você colocar um HTML, um texto ou qualquer outra coisa dentro. O seu servidor provavelmente está configurado para esperar um código PHP por causa da extensão `.php` e chamará o interpretador do PHP que espera um código que pode ser executado corretamente.

Uma outra dica é que orientação a objeto é mais uma coisa conceitual do que técnica. Se não dominar muito bem é melhor nem usar. Em PHP tem bem pouca vantagem no seu uso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Que conhecimentos você me recomendaria aprender para evoluir no uso do PHP?