# Faz alguma diferença usar .class.php?

Tags: php

Muda alguma coisa usar .class.php exemplo: conn.class.php

Sempre que pesquiso sobre aparece sobre classe e a programação em si!

Comment: Até aonde sei não, o que importa é o último ponto, o .class é colocado apenas por organização (o que são classes e o que não são)

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266120/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falando sobre convenções, como a PSR4, não se deve colocar o `.class.php` pois isso irá influenciar com o *autoload* da classe via *namespace*.

Tirando isso não muda nada. Na verdade nem precisa do `.php`, ele só é usado para facilitar ao *webserver* que aquele arquivo ele deve delegar para o interpretador do PHP.

Outro exemplo são aplicações em linha de comando que não tem extensão nenhuma, como o `composer` por exemplo.